# How to convert python code to application

Tags: python-3.7

I recently started learning python I wanted to know if I can convert my python code(in pycharm) to some sort of application which can be run without the IDE on other computers.(somewhat like we can run Android application by converting them to APK and use them on phones)

Answer (score 0):

One approach you can take is, use a framework like `flask`, `Django`, and host it.

Secondly, you can use `pyinstaller` to make your `python` script into a Windows, Mac and Linux executable

Answer (score 0):

There may be multiple answers for this, but one answer would be to use Auto-Py-To-Exe to convert python code to executables, which can be ran standalone in Windows.

You can find it at https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/.

Answer (score 0):

USE Pyinstaller:

In Linux (Tested on Ubuntu):

```
pyinstaller --onefile filename.py
```

In default, pyinstaller loads all the modules which makes the file bigger in size.
To avoid this, you can exclude modules like this

```
 pyinstaller --onefile --exclude matplotlib --exclude scipy --exclude pandas --exclude numpy filename.py
```

If pyinstaller misses your module, you can import like this

```
 pyinstaller --onefile  --hidden-import=module_name filename.py
```